# Drag and drop - Freecell

Tags: javascript, project

I'm currently playing around with JS and experimenting with a drag-and-drop system. However I'm looking for existing libraries that I can use to animate the dragging of cards. What are some good options to try out?

Comment: If you are allowed to use jQuery, then sugest that you have a look at [jQueryUI draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/), although your lecturer might see this as cheating :)

Answer (score 1):

You must bind drag events and drop targets to your cards. If you are allowed to use external libraries, I would suggest looking at [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/).

Have you tried looking at some developer resources?

- [Mozilla Developer Network: Drag and drop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DragDrop/Drag_and_Drop)
- [Mac Developer Library: Using Drag and Drop From JavaScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/DragAndDrop.html)
- [MSDN: DragEvent object (Internet Explorer)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974339%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Dev.Opera: HTML5 Drag and Drop](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/drag-and-drop/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't expect this to be easy, here are some basic examples where you can start with and draw your images on the results of your drops. Try experimenting a bit.

[Try checking out JQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

[Here is a pretty decent example for javascript registering the position of your cursor and capturing your mouse up and downs](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/mk/column2/index.html)

[HTML5 is another possibility](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp)

Comment: You beat me to the answer, but the W3Schools example is actually terrible...

Comment: just as an example :) everyone can use google if they need some more details ;)